# Convert an integer to a string in R

Tags: r

I have an integer

```
a <- (0:3)
```

And I would like to convert it to a character string that looks like this

```
b <- "(0:3)"
```

I have tried

```
as.character(a)
[1] "0" "1" "2" "3"
```

and

```
toString(a)
[1] "0, 1, 2, 3"
```

But neither do exactly what I need to do.

Can anyone help me get from a to b?

Many thanks in advance!

Comment: Isn't it an [X-y problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)

Comment: @Emmanuel-Lin Not necessarily; if I have a list of numbers, and I want to plot labels on a graph in the form of `"Country - Population"`, like `"Netherlands, 17000000"` then it might be a valid problem in OP's regard.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
paste0("(", min(a), ":", max(a), ")")
"(0:3)"
```

Or more concisely with sprintf():

```
sprintf("(%d:%d)", min(a), max(a))
```

Answer (score 5):

One option is `deparse` and `paste` the brackets

```
as.character(glue::glue('({deparse(a)})'))
#[1] "(0:3)"
```

---

Another option would be to store as a quosure and then convert it to character

```
library(rlang)
a <- quo((0:3))
quo_name(a)
#[1] "(0:3)"
```

it can be evaluated with `eval_tidy`

```
eval_tidy(a)
#[1] 0 1 2 3
```